# Open Reporting Services Project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, windows-10, business-intelligence

I recently got a new laptop with Windows 10 and need to get Visual Studio 2010 working with a Reporting Services Project. I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate downloaded and have tried numerous times to download the SSDT for VS 2010 but I still do not see the option for Reporting Services projects .rptproj as a project type in Visual Studio 2010. What am I missing?

I found the SSDT download here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014

No Reporting Services Option available:
[image]

Comment: Reporting Services Templates are normally in the "Other Project Types" group. However, I'm not sure if SSRS was supported in VS2010, certainly SSRS2008 was not supported. I had to use VS2008 for SSRS until VS2015 was released which did support the old SSRS project types.

Comment: I've been using VS 2010 for about 3 years now on the current reporting project my company has. The problem appears now that they gave me a new laptop and trying to configure VS so I can open the project again. I think the issue may be that I need SQL Server 2012 as noted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e46c34c7-cd53-4784-bae9-c9b19322bec4/cant-open-rptproj-vs2010?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 doesn't feature the Business Intelligence template. You'll need least 2012 for that.